# How do I get dynamic content (numbers) in xpath

Tags: xpath

I have few posts with dynamic numbers in the end of the DIV, how can I get the content inside the div with xPath?
The example codes:

```
<div class="OpenMediaElement_Video video-player video-item-50384">
<div class="OpenMediaElement_Video video-player video-item-46789">
<div class="OpenMediaElement_Video video-player video-item-16575">
```

It's pattern of 5 numbers each time.
I tries this code but don't works,

```
//div[starts-with(@class,"OpenMediaElement_Video video-player video-item-")]
```

Regards.

Comment: Try to use contains instead of starts-with. If you need the text you can add /text() after the xpath, if not then please give more details related to what you need and how do you use xpath.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) What is the result of your try? It does not look wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I use in wordpress plugin, that use xPath to igonre some parts from RSS. The div class="OpenMediaElement_Video .. is video, and I want that the plugin will not grab it, and I don't know how to do it. as I said, I tried what I wrote above, and it's not works.